# R: Splitting of column into two

Tags: r, split

Hi i have this table made from the package Publish and the function is called univariatetable.

```
> > table1 = summary(univariateTable(vaccinated~Sex+Agegrp+Q(SampleAge)+variable1+variable2+etc.etc.
>                                  data = hospital),
>                  show.pvalues=F)
```

The table i get is something like this that shows frequency and percentage in parantheses (I have just put artificial numbers and not all variables):

| Variable | LEVEL | Vaccinated =1 (n=52) | Vaccinated = 0 (n=34) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sex | M | 30 (57.7) | 60 (54.3) |
|  | F | 22 (42.3) | 46 (34.7) |

My wish is to split the columns vaccinated = 1 and vaccinated = 0 into 4 seperate columns : one for the frequency and one for the percentages. How can I do so, while keeping all the other variables in the table?

i have tried this but it doesnt keep all variables from the table

```
str_split_fixed(table1$`vaccinated = 0 (n=34)`, " ", 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

ToNumeric <- function(x) {
   as.numeric(gsub(" |\\)", "", x))
}

new_table <- bind_cols(
   tstrsplit(table1$x1, "\\("),
   tstrsplit(table1$x2, "\\(")
) %>% data.frame() %>% apply(2, ToNumeric)
```

Where table1 is your dataset, and "x1" and "x2" is like "Vaccinated =1 (n=52)" and "Vaccinated = 0 (n=34)". new_table has no colnames, you should set it manually.

Comment: It works - it gives me 4 columns now, instead of the two - but it does not keep the other columns in my table - how can I expres that in the code

Comment: You can use: ... %>% apply(2, ToNumeric) %>% bind_cols(table1[, -c(3, 4)])

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Data: (Note the properly formatted variable labels!)

```
df <- data.frame(
  Variable = c("Sex", NA),  
  LEVEL = c("M", "F"),
  Vaccinated_1_n_52 = c("30 (57.7)", "60 (54.3)"),  
  Vaccinated_0_n_34 = c("22 (42.3)", "46 (34.7)"))
```

Now `extract` the relevant data into columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(col = Vaccinated_1_n_52,
          into = c("Freq_Vacc_1", "Pctg_Vacc_1"),
          regex = "(\\d+)\\D+([\\d.]+)",
          convert = TRUE) %>%
  extract(col = Vaccinated_0_n_34,
          into = c("Freq_Vacc_0", "Pctg_Vacc_0"),
          regex = "(\\d+)\\D+([\\d.]+)",
          convert = TRUE) %>%
  cbind(df[,3:4], .) # omit this step if you don't need the original col's
  Vaccinated_1_n_52 Vaccinated_0_n_34 Variable LEVEL Freq_Vacc_1 Pctg_Vacc_1 Freq_Vacc_0
1         30 (57.7)         22 (42.3)      Sex     M          30        57.7          22
2         60 (54.3)         46 (34.7)     <NA>     F          60        54.3          46
  Pctg_Vacc_0
1        42.3
2        34.7
```

Comment: I dont want to make a new column called Num_vacc, but rather keep the vaccinated = 1 and 0 as to seperate columns - and then make two new columns that have the percentages in it - is that not possible?